# Cannot use declared JList - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I work with WindowBuilder and got a JFrame.
I have already declared and put in a JList called `dataset_list`:

```
    JList<String> dataset_list = new JList<String>();
    dataset_list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    dataset_list.setBounds(10, 245, 542, 106);
    panel.add(dataset_list);
```

in the main function of the program.

In a subfunction called `query` I want to add lines to that list, but cannot use the declared JList. I have also tried to use something like `<mainfunction>.dataset_list` but it wont work.

What am I missing (quiet new to GUI-Java)?

Comment: variables are only visible in their block. Declare it outside your main method. Before dealing with GUI I would also suggest to learn the Java Basics first.

Comment: As I have already programmed a long time in another language I am familiar with variables... And with that I even know that variables are specified for their block, but your solution does not work either.

Comment: If you want to access it from your main method it should also be static. Can't help without more code, but the compiler should tell you what's wrong...

Comment: @Bene The static did the job! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need to declare it as static for it to work, then you've got other subtle but important problems as this field shouldn't need to be static. This suggests that you're doing far too much within the static world, perhaps within the main method. Java is an object-oriented language and is best used in an OOP way, and by putting too much within static land you make your code more difficult to debug, test, mock, and enhance. Consider making that field an instance (non-static) field and only use it in a non-static way.

Comment: Also in the future if you have questions about compilation errors, please post the full error message with your question.

Comment: If you’re happy, I don’t want to take that away from you. :-) For production quality code, static variables are generally frowned upon. You might want to go the other way, create an instance of your class and then have the instance methods only access the (non-static) field `dataset_list`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Interesting... I took out a few things that had to do with static and now it works without.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the advice. As said, I am not used to Java and in FreePascal I have never used something like static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer gets posted so this question gets an answer! It is CW so I do not earn any rep for it.

There were two things causing my problem:

1. I had to declare the List outside of the main method to kame it visible to the subMethod.
2. I had to set it `static` as well as well as the method or better as now that I worked further on the project this was for do what @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested, create an instance of my class and access it somewhere else and **NOT** from the main method.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `dataset_list` inside `main` method so you can't reference to it in other methods. Try declare it outside the `main` method.

```
    class SomeClass {
        private JList<String> dataset_list = new JList<String>();

        public static void main(String... args) {
            // your code, you can add lines in your list
        }

        private void submethod() {
            //some other code, you can also add lines in your list here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that out and it does not work either. It stand right under the opening braces of the class and I cannot use it in the submethod...

Comment: Could you please provide a little more code then? Maybe there is something else wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks to Bene who added a `static` it works now. Thanks for your help tho :)